# How to avoid long list of data in Django view's render function?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django and am trying to build my first Django website. The content of my website requires a lot of data retrieved from my database(i.e. bar charts of latest data) and currently my solution to this is using the `render(request, 'index.html', data)` function to pass `data` to index.html template and use something like `var salesValue = {{salesValue|safe}}` to use the values.

The `data` dictionary looks like this in my view function. I have omitted the code for data extraction/formatting of the queryresults for simplicity:

```
queryresult0 = model0.objects.filter(...) 
queryresult1 = model1.objects.filter(...)
queryresult2 = model2.objects.filter(...)
...
data = {
          'salesValue0' : queryresult,
          'salesValue1' : queryresult1,          
          'salesValue2' : queryresult2,
          ...(and so on and so on)   
       }
```

These values are separate variables because the database queries involve multiple tables in multiple databases.

This solution works (though I'm not sure it's a good practice) but it didn't take long before the  `data` dictionary gets so long that it's hard to keep track of everything, plus the code gets very clumsy as well.

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to send lots of data to template? Maybe Switch to model base view instead of function based view? Use AJAX calls? Or maybe I should not be doing this in Django? Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks in advance and I apologize if this question seems like an open-ended question, but really it is a very specific problem that's troubling me:)

Comment: Some details are missing, if you just need to use a subset of data you can always filter the data using filter queries. ModelForms help you create forms connected to data with very less code, but the code flow is still the same. Have you tried Django Paginator?

If you want to load the page first and with spinner load the data then ajax is also possible workaround

Comment: You can use pagination to show data

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. All data fit in one page but there are too many variables(i.e. 20 salesvalue graph, each with its own dataset) and because my data is scattered in different table across multiple data base, I'm forced to put a long list of data into the data dictionary. Please see the updated question detail. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use the dictionary to store `queryresult` instead so that in the template you can index them easily.